# Normalizing data by reducing the sum

Tags: r, normalization

I would like to normalize data (consisting of ID and samples with number of species) column-wise by randomly reducing the sum, which is now different in every column, to reach a sum of 100 in each column. Here is an example of a table:

```
   ID   S1   S2   S3
1  1    0    0    3
2  2    0    0    0
3  3 5377 6140 7668
4  4  288  416 1121
5  5  876  786 1979
6  6  407  522 3792
```

Only values >0 should be taken into account, as the species number cannot be negative. I would appreciate any ideas!

Comment: Multiply by 100/rowsum? Please describe the algorithm you'd like to use.

Answer (score 1):

You did not explain why there could be negative data or how to deal with them. Usually I'd do

```
expl <- data.frame(ID = 1:6,
                   S1 = c(0,0,5377,288,876,407),
                   S2 = c(0,0,6140,416,786,522),
                   S3 = c(3,0,7668,1121,1979,3792))

norm.expl <- apply(expl,2, function(row) row/sum(row)*100)

print(norm.expl)
```

but with negative data in place maybe

```
expl <- data.frame(ID = 1:6,
                   S1 = c(0,0,5377,288,876,407),
                   S2 = c(0,0,6140,416,786,522),
                   S3 = c(3,0,7668,1121,1979,3792),
                   S4 = c(-1,-2,-3,100,0,100))

norm.expl2 <- apply(expl,2,function(row) {row <- row * (row>0); row/sum(row)*100})
print(norm.expl2)
```

which sets formerly neagtive values to 0.